# How to tell EntityFramework 5.0 that there's a one-to-one association between two entities?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I could go into the EDMX in design view and update the cardinality (1-*, 0-*, etc.) of associations, but I want to know if it is alright to do that in this scenario.

I have these two tables, let's say:

```
User
-----
Id


UserProfile
-------------
Id
UserId
Stuff
```

A single user may have just one profile. Therefore, I have set a UNIQUE constraint no the `UserId` column in the `UserProfile` table. Also, `UserProfile.Id` is defined as a foreign key that references `User.Id`.

However, in the Entity Framework model, I get the following:

```
class User
{
  ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

At first, I had the `UserProfile` table without any primary key of its own like this:

```
UserProfile
--------------
UserId
Stuff
```

But EntityFramework made that read-only as it needed to have a primary key on every table that you want to be made writable. So, I put an `Id` column in the `UserProfile` table as well.

**UPDATE**

I tried setting the multiplicit/cardinality of the association between the `User` table and the `UserProfile` table in my EDMX in the designer. However, I get this error suggesting I should turn it back to what it was, i.e. a one-to-many relationship.

```
Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserBasicProfile' 
in relationship 'FK_UserBasicProfile_User'. Because the Dependent Role 
properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity 
of the Dependent Role must be *.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way. Well, not purely a 1-1 relationship but a 1-0..1 relationship was what I was after, which, for all practical purposes is a one-to-one relationship.

If you ever fall into this trap like I described in my question, here's what you do:

1) Remove the `Id` field from the *dependent* table, in this case the `UserProfile` table. Therefore, do not give it a separate primary key.

2) Instead, mark the foreign key in the *dependent* table as its own primary key. In this case, mark the `UserId` field itself as the primary key of the `UserProfile` table.

In addition to these two, I assume, as I outlined in the question that you've got a primary and foreign key relationship between the *authority* (the `User` table in this case) and the *dependent* table (the `UserProfile` table in this example).

So, you new table structure should look like this:

```
User
------
Id


UserProfile
-------------
UserId (foreign key, and also the primary key of this UserProfile table)
Stuff
```

Entity Framework will then recognize this 1-0..1 relationship.