# EntityFramework One to One Assocation

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to use Conventions over Configuration in EF Code First to define a 0..1 - 1 association... However I am encountering an error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Bar' and 'Foo'. The principal end of this association must be
>   explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data
>   annotations.

My POCO classes are as follows:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Overridable Property Bar As Bar
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property FooID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Overridable Property Foo As Foo
End Class
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Here are some resources I am using:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

[How to tell EntityFramework 5.0 that there's a one-to-one association between two entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117279/how-to-tell-entityframework-5-0-that-theres-a-one-to-one-association-between-tw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree in the solutions that were chosen by @DavidG to resolve your problem but I guess you principal end in your one to one relationship is `Foo` entity. So, in the first variant, if you want to work with a FK property your `Bar`entity  (which is the dependend ent) has to be configured this way:

```
Public Class Bar
   <Key(), ForeignKey("Foo")>
   Public Property FooID As Integer
   Public Property Description As String
   Public Overridable Property Foo As Foo
End Class
```

Now, about the second variant (using the `Required` data annotation), the `FooId` FK property should be deleted, because, as I said before, in one to one relationship, the PK property in the dependent end also has to be FK. So, if you want to use this variant work only with the navigation properties:

```
 Public Class Bar
   Public Property ID As Integer
   Public Property Description As String
   <Required()>
   Public Overridable Property Foo As Foo
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have resources you can share on this subject?

Comment: Take a look this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), and [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html) too

Answer (score 1):

With a one-to-one relationship, one of the classes must be principal and the other dependant. Otherwise how would EF know which entry is to create first.

There are two ways to solve this. Either add `ForeignKey` attribute to the `ID` property on the `Foo` class:

```
Public Class Foo
    <Key(), ForeignKey("Foo")>
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Overridable Property Bar As Bar
End Class
```

Or add `Required` attribute to the `Foo` property in `Bar`:

```
Public Class Bar
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property FooID As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    <Required()>
    Public Overridable Property Foo As Foo
End Class
```

PS Been a while since I've done VB, hope this code works!

Comment: There is an small problem in the second variant, `FooID` in the `Bar` entity doesn't work as a FK because, as you explain in the first variant, the PK of the dependent end also has to be FK. If you want to work with this variant, remove the `FooId` property, and work just with the navigation properties

Comment: Do you have resources you can share on this subject?